# Json File Generation

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I Need some help in generating JSON Files from a database table. Below is my sample json generated through tsql code (using SQL Server 2017)

```
{  "TBLEMPLOYEES":[  
  {  
     "ID":1,
     "NAME":"SURESH",
     "SALARY":1000,
     "ADDRESS":{  
        "EMP_ADDRESS":"101 A ADDRESS1",
        "OTHERS":{  
           "EMP_PHONE":"987-654-4567",
           "EMP_CITY":"CITY1"
        }
     }
  },
  {  
     "ID":2,
     "NAME":"RAMESH",
     "SALARY":2000,
     "ADDRESS":{  
        "EMP_ADDRESS":"125 A ADDRESS2",
        "OTHERS":{  
           "EMP_PHONE":"588-654-4567",
           "EMP_CITY":"CITY2"
        }
     }
  }
```

]
}

Below is the TSQL code that i'm using to generate the JSON output in SSMS

```
SELECT ID AS "ID", EMP_NAME AS "NAME", EMP_SALARY AS "SALARY",EMP_ADDRESS  AS "ADDRESS.EMP_ADDRESS", EMP_PHONE AS "ADDRESS.OTHERS.EMP_PHONE", EMP_CITY AS "ADDRESS.OTHERS.EMP_CITY" FROM TBLEMPLOYEES FOR JSON path, root('TBLEMPLOYEES')
```

Now issue is when I try to use the same query from winform application using C#.net im not getting the correct Json File format. Its having no data in it.

Here is the code that i'm using

```
var queryWithForJson = "SELECT ID AS \"ID\", EMP_NAME AS \"NAME\",  EMP_SALARY AS \"SALARY\",EMP_ADDRESS AS \"ADDRESS.EMP_ADDRESS\", EMP_PHONE AS \"ADDRESS.OTHERS.EMP_PHONE\", EMP_CITY AS \"ADDRESS.OTHERS.EMP_CITY\" FROM TBLEMPLOYEES FOR JSON PATH, ROOT('TBLEMPLOYEES')";

        string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

        var conn = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS01;Database=Sample_2018;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryWithForJson, conn);
        conn.Open();
        var jsonResult = new StringBuilder();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            jsonResult.Append("[]");
        }
        else
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                jsonResult.Append(reader.GetValue(0).ToString());
            }
        }

        System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Output\TestJson.json");
        file.WriteLine(jsonResult.ToString());
```

Please let me know correct procedure to output JSON data (with same format) from database table to a JSON file.

Comment: what is the value of reader.HasRows ? if it's true what is the value of jsonResult after reader.Read()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not problem of your query because it returns same json when you directly execute on SSMS or by using c# code.

The main cause that you are not writing your data to json file.

So for that you have to use `StreamWriter.Flush();`. like

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"D:\Output\TestJson.json");
file.WriteLine(xml.ToString());
file.Flush();       //<== This method write your buffered stream data to file.
file.Close();       //<== This method closes current stream.
```

**StreamWriter.Flush()**:

Clears all buffers for the current writer and causes any buffered data to be
written to the underlying stream.

In simple words your buffered data in stream is written by `Flush()` method.

Comment: Thanks! its worked, I got the correct output file in proper format. Small mistake I missed it..

Comment: if my answer was helpful to you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and vote up by cliking up arrow. :)